# Set max-height embed element inside a embed-responsive bootstrap class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, embed, pygal

I'm trying to insert an interactive plot using `<embed src="..."></embed>` and make it responsive with bootstrap. Works fine but I want to reduce the max size of the chart and I can't find a solution. This is the working (but huge) plot:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <embed src="{{payment_methods_plots[account]}}"></embed>
</div>
```

My three failed approaches are:

1. Putting inside a div and style it with CSS `style="max-height: ...px;"`: Cut the image by half.
2. Use the `height` property of `<embed>`: Not working.
3. Trying to add the CSS property `(max-height: ...px;)` to `embed-responsive-4by3`: Failed.

**EDIT**: The charts are dynamic charts generated by pygal python library (codified in base64 ). This is an example of a graph:

https://jsfiddle.net/e6L5oLxe/

Comment: your points are evil (666), so I'm reluctant to change them with an upvote, lol :)

Comment: lol  "the cursed rep of SO"

Answer (score -1):

Try use !important in `embed-responsive-4by3` and take a look at his parent and set max-height there.

If none of these solutions work, please provide to us a *jsFiddle* or *plunker* example.

Comment: Thank you Yuri. I'm going to attach a jsFiddle example of the chart.